# Не получается создать пустой Observable

Tags: java, rxjava

Я пытаюсь создать пустой `Observalbe`, чтобы запустить создание образа жесткого диска (долгая операция) в IO потоке:

```
    Observable.empty()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(o -> {
                try {
                    imageCreater.createImage(creatingImageObject, new File(imageCreateView.getImagePath()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    imageCreateView.onError(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Однако, ничего не происходит. Если исправить `Observable.empty()` на `Observable.just(1)` — все начинает работать!

---

Из-за чего так происходит?

Answer (score 7):

Если вы создаете `Observable` методом `Observable.empty`, то такой `Observable` выдаст только событие `onCompleted` и больше ничего, т.е. событие `onNext` никогда не будет вызвано и ваш код, подписанный (в `subscribe`) на это событие, никогда не выполнится.

`Observable.just` создает `Observable`, который выдаст заранее определенное количество значений (в вашем случае - это одно значение = 1), после чего завершится. Таким образом, событие `onNext`, на которое вы подписываетесь в `subscribe` будет вызвано единожды и ваш код выполнится 1 раз.

**UPD:**

В первом случае (при использовании Observable.empty), ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
Observable.empty()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            value -> {},
            throwable -> {},
            () -> {
                try {
                    imageCreater.createImage(creatingImageObject, new File(imageCreateView.getImagePath()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    imageCreateView.onError(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
);
```